# Align 3 div's with auto margins

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to align 3 sections in one line: one left, one in center and one on right.
How can I do that?

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
    <div class="div3"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container{
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    height:auto;
  }

.div1{background: lime;border: 1px solid #ccc;width:100px;height: 100px; float: left}
.div2{background: yellow;border: 1px solid #ccc;width:100px;height: 100px; float:left}
.div3{background: orange;border: 1px solid #ccc;width:100px;height: 100px; float: right}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ux4DD/164/

Comment: Do you need to support older browser too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move div 3 to top of all div and add `margin: 0px auto;` to second div.

http://jsfiddle.net/ux4DD/165/

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align:center` to #container and remove `float:left` from the middle div

```
    #container{
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
    width: 100%;
     text-align:center; padding:0; font-size:0
  }
.div1{background: lime;border: 1px solid #ccc;width:100px;height: 100px; float: left; font-size:14px }
.div2{background: yellow;border: 1px solid #ccc;width:100px;height: 100px; display:inline-block; font-size:14px}
.div3{background: orange;border: 1px solid #ccc;width:100px;height: 100px; float: right; font-size:14px }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ux4DD/169/)**

Comment: There is an extra whitespace below.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov its removed